# clickable svg logo transparent part not linkable

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator, graphical-logo, xlink

I have a logo in SVG format that I want to be fully clickable.
With an imagemap setup through Illustrator it now links to my webpage, but I want the whole rectangle area of the logo to be clickable, not just the contours of the logo.

Comment: put a rect over the logo that has neither fill nor stroke and make it pointer-events:all